# Grid System in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am really new to Xamarin and I want to create 4 rows and the first one covers the whole screen, the second one has 5 columns, the third one has 4 columns and the last one has 2 columns. Currently, it looks like this:
[image]

So how can I make this screen proper with the grid system? Is there an efficient way to do it? Here is my code:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <BoxView Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                 Color="Red" />
        <Label Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
               Text="Table"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                 Color="CornflowerBlue" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1"
               Text="1x"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Color="DodgerBlue" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Text="2x"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Column="2"
                 Color="DarkSlateBlue" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="2"
               Text="3x"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Column="3"
                 Color="DarkSlateBlue" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="3"
               Text="4x"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Column="4"
                 Color="DarkSlateBlue" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="4"
               Text="+"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="2"
                 Color="CornflowerBlue" />
        <Label Grid.Row="2"
               Text="Page 1"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="2"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Color="DodgerBlue" />
        <Label Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Text="Page 2"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="2"
                 Grid.Column="2"
                 Color="DarkSlateBlue" />
        <Label Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="2"
               Text="Page 3"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="2"
                 Grid.Column="3"
                 Color="DarkSlateBlue" />
        <Label Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="3"
               Text="Page 4"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="3"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 Color="Red" />
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Text="Cancel"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
                Background="Red"/>
        <BoxView Grid.Row="3"
                 Grid.Column="2"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 Color="Green" />
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Text="Place Order"
                 Grid.Column="2"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
                Background="Green"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: there are generally two approaches.  1) figure out the least common multiple needed for all of your cols (in your case, 20) and use that as a basis for your grid.  Or 2) use a master grid with one big col and then sub-grids with the correct number of cols for each row

Comment: And your design image please? And try a few nested layouts would be easier to settle the elements.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this ,we can use `Grid`,`RelativeLayout` etc to contain our controls.

Of course, `Grid` is a good layout to achieve this just as you have used, and we can also use inner layouts simplify the codes in the external grid.

For example, we can use the following code to replace Label `1x` ,`Page 1` and  two `BoxView` with  property :`Color="CornflowerBlue"`. This way the code looks less scattered and simpler.

```
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" BackgroundColor="Yellow"    >
        <Label  
           HeightRequest="50"    
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
           Text="1x"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />

        <Label   
           HeightRequest="50"
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
           Text="Page 1"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />

    </StackLayout>
```

**Note:**

Of course, there's more than one way. Use internal layouts to make code leaner. Depending on your idea, you can modify your code as much as you like.